# Change condition when combobox is used

Tags: c#, combobox

Currently using C# in Visual Studio 2013 make a program where I want something on the screen to become available once the user has selected any value from a combobox. So far I have made this:

```
        if (cmbTickets.SelectedIndex == 10)
        {
            enableSeats();

        }
```

When this is used the item on the screen becomes available only when the number ten is chosen from the combobox. I wan this to happen however when any of the options in the combobox is selected. What value should I place in the if statement to do this?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Subscribe to the `SelectedIndexChanged` event.

The `SelectedIndex` is `-1` when no selection has been made, so just reference that.

```
private void comboBox1_SelectedIndexChanged(object sender, EventArgs e)
{
    if (comboBox1.SelectedIndex > -1)
        enableSeats();
}
```